# ng-class behavior not clear

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I was executing the below code (from "AngularJS" by Brad Green & Shyam Seshadri-O'Reilly).
 The below code sets background color as "Red", for the selected row in the table, as well as removes the background color from the previously selected row.
 For example, if i click on row #1 its background will be set to "red", then if i click on row #2, it's background will be set to "red"
 as well as background color of row #1 becomes normal (ie. it's not red now).

I am not clear on the fact that even though I have not written code to re-set the background color of other rows, how it's being reset ?

```
    <!-- View/Html -->
    .selected {
        background-color: red;
        }

    <table ng-controller="DynamicStyleCtrl">
        <tr ng-repeat='resturant in directory' ng-click='selectResturant($index)'
            ng-class='{selected: $index==selectedRow}'>
            <td>{{resturant.name}}</td>
            <td>{{resturant.cuisine}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

      <!-- Controller -->
      function DynamicStyleCtrl($scope) {
         $scope.directory = [
                        {name:'The Handsome Heifer', cusine:'BBQ'},
                        {name:'Greens', cusine:'Salads'},
                        {name:'Fine Fish', cusine:'Sea food'}
                      ];
             $scope.selectResturant = function(row){
             $scope.selectedRow=row;
           }
         }
```

Comment: All bindings are recalculated on each `$digest` cycle, so expression for `selected` is recalculated for each row

Comment: What you're seeing is Angular's `$digest` loop in action: the `ng-class` directive allows you to bind CSS classes to DOM elements, conditionally, based on some expression. References within these expressions are added to Angular's `$watch` list, a collection of references to scope properties (or other variables) which may change in response to browser events. When an event occurs, Angular may call its `$digest` loop, in which it uses its `$watch` list to update data bindings (on the page) or trigger `$watch` callbacks (inside of your controllers), keeping your application in sync.

Comment: Thank you Kirill and Michael for explaining this, it answers my question. Now i can understand that as the property "selectedRow" belongs to $scope, any change in this property will reset all the bindings

Answer (score 4):

The following code will apply the class 'selected' when $index === selected row

```
ng-class='{selected: $index==selectedRow}'
```

So, when the row is selected (via ng-click) the row will have the class 'selected' which will set the background-color to red because of the css below:

```
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

When the row is not selected because another row is selected, the 'selected' class that was applied via ng-class will be removed and the corresponding css will no longer be applied, therefore it will no longer be red.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think $digest loop.../binding reset... explains this behavior clearly.